# When is the strict transform of very ample divisor ample?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, blow-ups, positivity, ample-bundles

Let $X$ be a projective variety and $Y \subset X$ is a very ample divisor on $X$. Let $Z \subset X$ be a regular subvariety (but $X$ need not be regular along $Z$) of codimension $2$ and $\pi:\tilde{X} \to X$ be  the blow-up of $X$ along $Z$. Is there any known condition under which the strict transform of $Y$ in $\tilde{X}$ is ample?

**EDIT** Also assume that $Z$ is contained in $Y$.

Comment: Even for $X=\mathbb{P}^2$ and $Z$ finite (and reduced), it is a tricky question -- it depends not only on the number of points, but also on their position. I would be very surprised if anything could be said in your general setup.

Comment: @abx I do not know if this makes any difference, but in my case $Z$ is irreducible. In particular, translating to your example it is just one point. However, in my case $Z \subset Y$.

Comment: There are blow-ups of P3 along a curve, where the ample cone is extremely complicated, so I agree with abx